# Spring Boot exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Using IntelliJ IDEA, I connected to a MySQL database so that I will be able to use the tables as classes. With a module I've done that. But when I am trying to run an empty `Controller` the following exceptions are been thrown.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at eu.name.api.ClubapiApplication.main(ClubapiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:566) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:447) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:526) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:402) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$6(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b7577e9.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:594) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$32(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b7577e9.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c794fe3.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class eu.name.api.MainController
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

`ClubapiApplication.java`

```
package eu.name.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ClubapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClubapiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`MainController.java` which is the class that exception happens as you can see on the final exception message.

```
package eu.name.api;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/api")
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


}
```

`UserRepository`

```
package eu.name.api;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import eu.name.model.*;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

}
```

I can't post all the module database classes, I will post only `UserEntity.java` class which is not complete because I exceeded maximum lines on stackoverflow.

```
    package eu.name.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "mydb")
@IdClass(UserEntityPK.class)
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String role;
    @Column
    private byte active;
    @Column(name="company_name")
    private String companyName;
    @Column
    private String surname;
    @Column
    private String midname;
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private Timestamp birthDate;
    @Column
    private String street;
    @Column(name="street_no")
    private String streetNo;
    @Column
    private String zip;
    @Column
    private String phone;
    @Column
    private String mobile;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private byte authenticated;
    @Column(name="create_date")
    private Timestamp createDate;
    @Column(name="modify_date")
    private Timestamp modifyDate;
    @Column
    private String comments;
    @Column
    private String pin;
    private ConnectionEntity connectionById;
    private TransactionEntity transactionById;
    private TransactionEntity transactionById_0;
    @Column(name="category_id")
    private CategoryEntity categoryByCategoryId;
    @Column(name="city_id")
    private CityEntity cityByCityId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "role")
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "active")
    public byte getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(byte active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "surname")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }



    public void setAuthenticated(byte authenticated) {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    public Timestamp getModifyDate() {
        return modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(Timestamp modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "comments")
    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "pin")
    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (active != that.active) return false;
        if (authenticated != that.authenticated) return false;
        if (role != null ? !role.equals(that.role) : that.role != null) return false;
        if (companyName != null ? !companyName.equals(that.companyName) : that.companyName != null) return false;
        if (surname != null ? !surname.equals(that.surname) : that.surname != null) return false;
        if (midname != null ? !midname.equals(that.midname) : that.midname != null) return false;
        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(that.firstname) : that.firstname != null) return false;
        if (gender != null ? !gender.equals(that.gender) : that.gender != null) return false;
        if (birthDate != null ? !birthDate.equals(that.birthDate) : that.birthDate != null) return false;
        if (street != null ? !street.equals(that.street) : that.street != null) return false;
        if (streetNo != null ? !streetNo.equals(that.streetNo) : that.streetNo != null) return false;
        if (zip != null ? !zip.equals(that.zip) : that.zip != null) return false;
        if (phone != null ? !phone.equals(that.phone) : that.phone != null) return false;
        if (mobile != null ? !mobile.equals(that.mobile) : that.mobile != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (createDate != null ? !createDate.equals(that.createDate) : that.createDate != null) return false;
        if (modifyDate != null ? !modifyDate.equals(that.modifyDate) : that.modifyDate != null) return false;
        if (comments != null ? !comments.equals(that.comments) : that.comments != null) return false;
        if (pin != null ? !pin.equals(that.pin) : that.pin != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (role != null ? role.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (int) active;
        result = 31 * result + (companyName != null ? companyName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (surname != null ? surname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (midname != null ? midname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (gender != null ? gender.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (birthDate != null ? birthDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (street != null ? street.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (streetNo != null ? streetNo.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (zip != null ? zip.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mobile != null ? mobile.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (int) authenticated;
        result = 31 * result + (createDate != null ? createDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (modifyDate != null ? modifyDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (comments != null ? comments.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (pin != null ? pin.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public CategoryEntity getCategoryByCategoryId() {
        return categoryByCategoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryByCategoryId(CategoryEntity categoryByCategoryId) {
        this.categoryByCategoryId = categoryByCategoryId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public CityEntity getCityByCityId() {
        return cityByCityId;
    }

    public void setCityByCityId(CityEntity cityByCityId) {
        this.cityByCityId = cityByCityId;
    }
}
```

Database

[image]

Module

[image]

Project Structure

[image]

Database Scheme

[image]

**EDIT** I tested my project with a very simple database that contains only one table and two fields and the same exceptions are happening!

Comment: Where are you creating `userRepository` bean?

Comment: @alayor sorry I missed it. I edited the code. I made changes on `MainController` and added `UserRepository` class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `UserEntity` is in a different package.

Trying adding these annotations to your `ClubapiApplication` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"eu.upcom.api", "eu.upcom.model"})
```

Comment: It doesn't accept a comma between them. The annotation becomes red.

After your edit, sadly the same exceptions appear.

Comment: No worries, I saw it. I don't know if you saw my edit as well. The same exceptions are appearing. I added a database schema as well.

Comment: Try adding just @ComponentScan("com.upcom.*") along with @Configuration

Answer (score 0):

In my case while using multiple packages following worked :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"eu.upcom.api", "eu.upcom.model"})
```

where basePackages is an array of strings, nothing but the packages to scan. Don't know why eu.upcom.* didn't worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I solved it by including this in the MainContoller.java

```
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public MainController(UserRepository userRepository)
{
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two separate projects `shopmeCommon` and `shopmeWebParent` all the common stuff is in `shopemeCommon` project. My folder structure is like below. I am running `shopmeWebParent` project.

[image]

I got the error that said `cannot create the Repository Bean`. Actually, what's happening here. I gave the Role entity argument for `JpaRepository<>` and that entity is in `shopmeCommon` module. So spring cannot configure it. This exception firstly occurs here. so that's why it is show like repository exception.

At the start point of the app. Specify the Beans(entity and repository) packages under `@EntityScan({<package_path>})` array like below.

```
package com.shopme.admin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"com.shopme.common.entity", "com.shopme.admin.user"}) //this is the important line
public class ShopmeBackEndApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShopmeBackEndApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is related to the UserEntity class. The class itself has been annotated, but none of the properties are annotated.

Annotate your class like the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
@Column
private String role;
@Column
private byte active;
@Column(name="company_name") //Example to show how to change the name to match a differently named column in MySQL. 
private String companyName;
```

You may also find value in having your repository extend `JpaRepository` rather than the `CrudRepository` interface - it'll expose different method that are JPA specific such as `SaveAndFlush`

Comment: There are annotations above getters and setters that's why I included only one getter and setter to point at that. As for your other solution, the same exceptions are happening. Keep in minded that `UserEntity` and the other classes from `model` package, are created automatically from the MySQL database.

Comment: Annotations are extremely important in Spring - please update the above code and include your annotations so we can review - otherwise no one will have a hope of even pointing you in the right direction

Comment: The autogeneration isn't the issue - the problem is related to how your Entity classes are being wired up - the managed type exception is related to how Spring Data is trying to complete the auto wiring of the class - it sees that it needs to be wired but cant figure out how to do so

Comment: I updated the `UserRepository` and also added the auto generated getters and setters. As you can see, your suggestions were already implemented. But of course I added them again on variable declaration.

Comment: The getters and setters should not be annotated, what happens if you remove those annotations?

Comment: Same exceptions

Comment: I added database scheme if you want to take a look.

Comment: Have you tried using a stand-alone table (with no relations) and seeing if you can get it to work correctly?

Comment: I just did. A simple database with just one table and two fields and the same exceptions are happening!

Comment: Well something funky is going on - honestly I'd have to dig deeper than my time allows, final suggestion would be if you haven't already - spin up a new project all together, no MVC - just basic application and wire in your a JpaRepository for the table, an annotated POJO representing the table and a basic test to check functionality. If that works then build off that until you find your issue. I suppose its possible your issue is in your persistance.xml file - not too sure as I don't use one, but best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and your time

Answer (score -4):

UserRepository lacks @Repository annotation.

Comment: Still the same exceptions